# nulInCommit: NUL byte in the commit object body

Tags: github, git-rewrite-history, gitlab-ce

I'm trying to export one of my projects from GitLab to GitHub using command line using these steps. [Migrate project by commandline] (https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line)

However, the migration fails during push to remote repository and the error is "**nulInCommit: NUL byte in the commit object body**". This is because of the NUL byte in one of the commit history object.

I do know NUL byte error that we do face in commit message that we can reword by rebase but this error shows the error is at object body and also the specific commit I found is a **merge commit** and so I couldn't rebase/reword or change it in commit history.

Can someone please help me on how to fix this in the commit history of the Git project?

````
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
warning in commit 8affc08283444c3fe5c8a748e113bfd3545512dd: nulInCommit: NUL byte in the commit object body
Checking objects: 100% (117117/117117), done.```
````

Comment: Did the push complete successfully?  This says it was a warning, not an error.

Comment: Nope it failed with error remote rejected and the error i mentioned nullInCommit. The console log I put previously was obtained from 'git fsck' command to identify which commit is causing the error.


```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub normally runs `fsck` on all new objects to prevent corrupt or malicious objects from being pushed.  This is also the case for most other hosting sites.  However, if you're importing a project with an existing issue, they can sometimes remove the restriction for the initial import if you contact them.

If you do and they say they can't, you can rewrite the data by using something like the following:

```
$ git init ../new-repo
$ git fast-export --all | (cd ../new-repo && git fast-import && git checkout)
```

This will rewrite the history to contain only valid input and will invalidate any signatures on tags after that point, as well as change the object IDs.  It is possible that you'll need to edit the stream from `git fast-export --all` to remove the NUL byte manually; if so, you can redirect it to a file and edit that file, then send it to `git fast-import` in the new repo.

Comment: Hi @bk2204 . 

I get the could not write to blob error.

```git-fast-import statistics:
pack_report: getpagesize()            =      65536
pack_report: core.packedGitWindowSize = 1073741824
pack_report: core.packedGitLimit      = 35184372088832
pack_report: pack_used_ctr            =          0
pack_report: pack_mmap_calls          =          0
pack_report: pack_open_windows        =          0 /          0
pack_report: pack_mapped              =          0 /          0

fatal: could not write blob '555ff3548206e906f38e5f457f8a291f3ccfe46b': Invalid argument

Comment: You'll need to specify what operating system, Git version, and environment you're running with.  This is not an error you should normally receive, so it likely indicates some sort of system problem.

Comment: OS - Windows 10
Git Version - git version 2.25.1.windows.1
Environment - Git Bash (Java - JDK-1.8.0_161)

Comment: I tried in on of the Linux machine and this works fine now. Thanks a lot @bk2204. One more thing. After import I do see all the branches but however, I couldn't push them all to new repository directly. I tried the following and non of this pushes all branches but only master.
```
git push --all origin -u
git push origin '*:*'
```
I do have about 800 branches and repo size is in GBs. So, do you have any suggestion on how to push all the fast-imported branches to remote on new repository?

Comment: If you're having push problems, that should be a separate question.  There are too many possible things that can go wrong pushing for that to be suitably answered in a comment.